# This side can't be reached - angular in docker on Windows 10

Tags: angular, windows, docker, docker-compose

I want to use Docker in my project to start api (spring), database (H2) and frontend (angular) together by using docker-compose. Everything is compiling (using ***docker-compose build*** first and the ***docker-compose up*** to run project) and Terminal gives me adress where to reach my browser:

```
    D:\Applications\tasks-manager>docker-compose build
Building front
Step 1/8 : FROM node:latest
 ---> 91a3cf793116
Step 2/8 : COPY . ./frontend
 ---> 812a6411384a
Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /frontend
 ---> Running in 2fef15d985be
Removing intermediate container 2fef15d985be
 ---> ef7de8832794
Step 4/8 : COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
 ---> 820662c8bbda
Step 5/8 : CMD ["npm", "i"]
 ---> Running in 84400d20cce6
Removing intermediate container 84400d20cce6
 ---> 604cd69b6330
Step 6/8 : CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]
 ---> Running in 4965a5810f46
Removing intermediate container 4965a5810f46
 ---> fa6a7f31e02d
Step 7/8 : EXPOSE 4201
 ---> Running in 7d5f682bd8bc
Removing intermediate container 7d5f682bd8bc
 ---> a3bb717ec881
Step 8/8 : CMD ["npm", "start"]
 ---> Running in 23e17c2be839
Removing intermediate container 23e17c2be839
 ---> 3ecdf3141698
Successfully built 3ecdf3141698
Successfully tagged tasks-manager-angular:latest

D:\Applications\tasks-manager>docker-compose up
Creating network "tasks-manager_default" with the default driver
Creating tasks-manager-angular ... done
Attaching to tasks-manager-angular
tasks-manager-angular |
tasks-manager-angular | > frontend@0.0.0 start /frontend
tasks-manager-angular | > ng serve --port 4201 --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true
tasks-manager-angular |
tasks-manager-angular | WARNING: This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications
tasks-manager-angular | locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.
tasks-manager-angular |
tasks-manager-angular | Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or
tasks-manager-angular | computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in
tasks-manager-angular | websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disableHostCheck" if that's the
tasks-manager-angular | case.
tasks-manager-angular | WARNING: Running a server with --disable-host-check is a security risk. See https://medium.com/webpack/
webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a for more information.
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/animations/browser/testing : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/common/http/testing : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/core/testing : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/platform-browser/testing : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/compiler/testing : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/common/testing : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular | Compiling @angular/router/testing : es2015 as esm2015
tasks-manager-angular |
tasks-manager-angular | chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 113 kB [initial] [rendered]
tasks-manager-angular | chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 140 kB [initial] [rendered]
tasks-manager-angular | chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
tasks-manager-angular | chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 13.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
tasks-manager-angular | chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.4 MB [initial] [rendered]
tasks-manager-angular | Date: 2020-05-28T07:39:06.828Z - Hash: fd51e5bdf72f071a8134 - Time: 12980ms
tasks-manager-angular | ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:4201, open your browser on http://localhost:4201/ **
```

Issue which occured is error "This side can't be reached":

[image]

I think I've tried every solution found in google, and nothing changes. I think important information is that I am running docker on Windows 10. IDE - IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.

Bellow is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:latest

COPY . ./frontend
WORKDIR /frontend

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json

CMD ["npm", "i"]
CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]
EXPOSE 4201
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  front:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: tasks-manager-angular
    depends_on:
      - api
    ports:
      - "4201:4201"
    image: "tasks-manager-angular:latest"
    restart: always
```

**package.json**:

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4201 --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck true",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

If anybody fought with similar issue, and solved it, please give me any hint or idea where to find what I am doing wrong. Everything works perfectly when launched without using docker.

Comment: What's the address you're typing into your browser?  Are you using Docker Desktop or Docker Toolbox?  Can you replace the first image with the actual text output of your startup, and include the actual command you're running to start it (even if it's just `docker-compose up`)?

Comment: @DavidMaze the adress i'm typing is: http://localhost:4201/ . I am using Docker Toolbox. Sure few seconds after this answer I will add to my question actual text output and command which I use to run the program.

Comment: Why are you serving content in docker using angular? You do realise that this isn't for production use? You should be using an Nginx image or something to host your angular component

Comment: @Liam yes, I do realise, I want to use Nginx, because I found a lot of examples how to use it and it looks really usefull, but before using it I wanted to check how docker works with normal angular because I am totally new to docker and don't know yet how nginx works so I've decidec to implement it in future steps. This project is just for my own use and learn so it's not a problem right now. Anyway thanks for a hint :)

Comment: For Docker Toolbox, you need to connect to the `docker-machine ip` address, often 192.168.99.100, not `localhost`.

Comment: That's it! Thank you, now it works :) And by the way, if I would use Docker Desktop it would work with localhost?